# GCC compiler errors

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, bison, lex

I've successfully compiled a lexer and parser, as shown below. The final stage of compiling the .exe interpreter throws the errors.

Any help or hints as to what I've missed would be greatly appreciated.

```
me@PC /cygdrive/e/HUB/Archive/spl
$ gcc -o spl.exe spl.c parser.tab.c -lfl
spl.c:4:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
parser.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
parser.y:145:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘create_node’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘TERNARY_TREE’
parser.y:147:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘create_node’
parser.y:47:14: note: declared here
parser.y:149:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘create_node’
parser.y:47:14: note: declared here
parser.y:156:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘create_node’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘TERNARY_TREE’
parser.y:158:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘create_node’
parser.y:47:14: note: declared here
parser.y:160:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘create_node’
parser.y:47:14: note: declared here
parser.y:165:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘create_node’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘TERNARY_TREE’
parser.y:170:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘create_node’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘TERNARY_TREE’
parser.y:177:5: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘create_node’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘TERNARY_TREE’ but argument is of type ‘int’
parser.y:179:5: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘create_node’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘TERNARY_TREE’ but argument is of type ‘int’
parser.y:179:5: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘create_node’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘TERNARY_TREE’ but argument is of type ‘int’
parser.y:179:5: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘create_node’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘TERNARY_TREE’ but argument is of type ‘int’
parser.y:181:5: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘create_node’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘TERNARY_TREE’ but argument is of type ‘int’
parser.y:181:5: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘create_node’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘TERNARY_TREE’ but argument is of type ‘int’
parser.y:181:5: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘create_node’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
parser.y:47:14: note: expected ‘TERNARY_TREE’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

Lexer:

```
/* Declare Symbol Table Type and Array as imported types */
%{
extern SYMTABNODEPTR symTab[SYMTABSIZE];
extern int currentSymTabSize;
%}

delim       [ \t\n\r]
ws          {delim}+
letter      [A-Za-z]
digit       [0-9]
id          {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
number      {digit}+
charconst   "'"{letter}"'"

%%
                 int k;

{ws}         ; /* white space, do nothing */

ENDP         return(ENDP);
OF           return(OF);
TYPE         return(TYPE);
CODE         return(CODE);

";"          return(SEMICOLON);

IF           return(IF);
ENDIF        return(ENDIF);
THEN         return(THEN);
ELSE         return(ELSE);
WHILE        return(WHILE);

ENDWHILE     return(ENDWHILE);
DO           return(DO);
ENDDO        return(ENDDO);
DECLARATIONS return(DECLARATIONS);
CHARACTER    return(CHARACTER);
INTEGER      return(INTEGER);
REAL         return(REAL);
FOR          return(FOR);
ENDFOR       return(ENDFOR);
IS           return(IS);
BY           return(BY);
TO           return(TO);
WRITE        return(WRITE);
NEWLINE      return(NEWLINE);
READ         return(READ);
NOT          return(NOT);
AND          return(AND);
OR           return(OR);

"="          return(ASSIGNMENT);
"->"         return(OUTPUTTO);

{id}         return(ID);
{number}     {
                  /* call the library function to convert ascii to int */
                  /* assign the integer value of the text in yytext to 
                      the iVal part of the yylVal object */
                  yylval.iVal = atoi(yytext) ;
                  return(NUMBER);
                }
{charconst}  return(CHARCONST);
"+"          return(PLUS);
"-"          return(MINUS);
"<"          return(LT);
">"          return(GT);
"<>"         return(BETWEEN);
"<="         return(LESSEQUAL);
">="         return(GREATEREQUAL);
"."          return(POINT);
","          return(COMMA);
"/"          return(DIVIDE);
"*"          return(MULTIPLY);
"("          return(BRA);
")"          return(KET);
":"          return(COLON);

%%

/* Here is the code for the library of symbol table routines */

/* code for a simple symbol table, which is an array of pointers to
   structs, each of which contains an identifier.
*/


SYMTABNODEPTR newSymTabNode()
{
    return ((SYMTABNODEPTR)malloc(sizeof(SYMTABNODE)));
}


/* Look up an identifier in the symbol table, if its there return
   its index.  If its not there, put it in the end position,
   as long as the table isn't full, and return its index.
*/

int installId(char *id) 
{
    extern SYMTABNODEPTR symTab[SYMTABSIZE]; 
    extern int currentSymTabSize;
    int index;

    index = lookup(id);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        return (index);
    }
    else 
    {
       symTab[currentSymTabSize] = newSymTabNode();
       strcpy(symTab[currentSymTabSize]->identifier,id);
       return(currentSymTabSize++);
    }
}

int lookup(char *s)
{
    extern SYMTABNODEPTR symTab[SYMTABSIZE];
    extern int currentSymTabSize;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<currentSymTabSize; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(s,symTab[i]->identifier) == 0)
        {
            return (i);
        }
    }
    return (-1);    
}
```

Parser:

```
%{

/* Import the standard C I/O libraries */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* A Named constant denoting a null value in the tree */
#define NOTHING -1

/* These constants are used later in the code */
#define SYMTABSIZE     50
#define IDLENGTH       15
#define NOTHING        -1
#define INDENTOFFSET    2

enum ParseTreeNodeType { value, expression, constant, number_constant, term } ;  
                      /* Add more types here, as more nodes added to tree */

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE 1
#endif

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#endif

#ifndef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif                    

/* Define the Object Structure for a tree node to store
   the compiled result */

struct treeNode
{
    int  item;
    int  nodeIdentifier;
    struct treeNode *first;
    struct treeNode *second;
    struct treeNode *third;
};

typedef struct treeNode TREE_NODE;
typedef TREE_NODE *TERNARY_TREE;

int evaluate(TERNARY_TREE);
TERNARY_TREE create_node(int,int,TERNARY_TREE,TERNARY_TREE,TERNARY_TREE);

// Symbol table def

struct symTabNode {
    char identifier[IDLENGTH];
};

typedef  struct symTabNode SYMTABNODE;
typedef  SYMTABNODE        *SYMTABNODEPTR;

SYMTABNODEPTR  symTab[SYMTABSIZE]; 

int currentSymTabSize = 0;

%}

%start program

%union
{
    int iVal;
    TERNARY_TREE  tVal;
}

%token<iVal> PLUS MINUS MULTIPLY DIVIDE BRA KET CHARCONST ENDP OF TYPE CODE 
SEMICOLON IF ENDIF THEN ELSE WHILE ENDWHILE DO ENDDO DECLARATIONS CHARACTER 
INTEGER REAL FOR ENDFOR IS BY TO WRITE NEWLINE READ NOT AND OR LT GT BETWEEN 
LESSEQUAL GREATEREQUAL COMMA POINT COLON ASSIGNMENT OUTPUTTO 
ID NUMBER

%type<tVal> value expression constant number_constant term

%%

program              : ID COLON block ENDP ID POINT
                     ;
block                : CODE statement_list
                     | DECLARATIONS declaration_block CODE statement_list
                     ;
declaration_block    : id_list OF TYPE type SEMICOLON
                     | declaration_block id_list OF TYPE type SEMICOLON
                     ;
id_list              : ID
                     | ID COMMA id_list
                     ;
type                 : CHARACTER
                     | INTEGER
                     | REAL
                     ;
statement_list       : statement
                     | statement_list SEMICOLON statement
                     ;
statement_lists      : statement
                     | statement_list SEMICOLON statement
                     ;
statement            : assignment_statement
                     | if_statement
                     | do_statement
                     | while_statement
                     | for_statement
                     | write_statement
                     | read_statement
                     ;
assignment_statement : expression OUTPUTTO ID
                     ;
if_statement         : IF conditional THEN statement_lists ENDIF
                     | IF conditional THEN statement_lists ELSE statement_list ENDIF
                     ;
do_statement         : DO statement_list WHILE conditional ENDDO
                     ;
while_statement      : WHILE conditional DO statement_list ENDWHILE
                     ;
for_statement        : FOR ID IS expression BY expressions TO expression DO statement_list ENDFOR
                     ;
write_statement      : WRITE BRA output_list KET
                     | NEWLINE
                     ;
read_statement       : READ BRA ID KET
                     ;
output_list          : value
                     | value COMMA output_list
                     ;
condition            : expression comparator expression
                     ;
conditional          : condition
                     | NOT conditional
                     | condition AND conditional
                     | condition OR conditional
                     ;
comparator           : ASSIGNMENT
                     | BETWEEN
                     | LT
                     | GT
                     | LESSEQUAL
                     | GREATEREQUAL
                     ;
expression           : term
                     { $$ = create_node($1,term,NULL,NULL,NULL); }
                     | term PLUS expression
                     { $$ = create_node(NOTHING,PLUS,$1,$3); }
                     | term MINUS expression
                     { $$ = create_node(NOTHING,MINUS,$1,$3); }
                     ;
expressions          : term
                     | term PLUS expressions
                     | term MINUS expressions
                     ;
term                 : value
                     { $$ = create_node($1,term,NULL,NULL,NULL); }
                     | value MULTIPLY term
                     { $$ = create_node(NOTHING,MULTIPLY,$1,$3); }
                     | value DIVIDE term
                     { $$ = create_node(NOTHING,DIVIDE,$1,$3); }
                     ;
value                : ID
                     { $$ = create_node($1,ID,NULL,NULL,NULL); }
                     | constant
                     { $$ = create_node($1,constant,NULL,NULL,NULL); }
                     | BRA expression KET
                     { $$ = create_node(NOTHING,BRA,$2,NULL,NULL); }
                     ;
constant             : number_constant
                     { $$ = create_node($1,number_constant,NULL,NULL,NULL); }
                     | CHARCONST
                     { $$ = create_node($1,CHARCONST,NULL,NULL,NULL); }
                     ;
number_constant      : NUMBER
                     { $$ = create_node($1,NUMBER,NULL,NULL,NULL); }
                     | MINUS NUMBER
                     { $$ = create_node(NOTHING,MINUS,$2,NULL,NULL); }
                     | NUMBER POINT NUMBER
                     { $$ = create_node(NOTHING,REAL,$1,$2,$3); }
                     | MINUS NUMBER POINT NUMBER
                     { $$ = create_node(NOTHING,MINUS,$2,$3,$4); }
                     ;              
%%

TERNARY_TREE create_node(int ival, int case_identifier, TERNARY_TREE p1, TERNARY_TREE  p2, TERNARY_TREE  p3)
{
    TERNARY_TREE t;
    t = (TERNARY_TREE)malloc(sizeof(TREE_NODE));
    t->item = ival;
    t->nodeIdentifier = case_identifier;
    t->first = p1;
    t->second = p2;
    t->third = p3;
    return (t);
}

int evaluate(TERNARY_TREE t)
{
    if (t != NULL)
    {
    switch(t->nodeIdentifier)
        {
            case(NEWLINE) :
                return(evaluate(t->first));
            case(PLUS) :
                return((evaluate(t->first)) + (evaluate(t->second)));
            case(MULTIPLY) :
                return((evaluate(t->first)) * (evaluate(t->second)));
            case(BRA) :
                return(evaluate(t->first));
            case(NUMBER) :
        return(t->item);
        }
    }
}

#include "lex.yy.c"
```

Comment: Please use `gcc -Wall -g` to compile, and learn to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile errors come from the `$$ = create_node(NOTHING,PLUS,$1,$3);` calls, where `create_node` is called with 4 parameters, while it expects 5.

But they are not the only problem, since there also `create_node` calls, where the first parameter is assigned from an `TERNARY_TREE` instead of an integer (on occurrence is the expression:term{...} rule).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I no longer have these errors, but now some different ones that I'll create in a new question.